# How can I Hash hundred thousand records taken as a input from CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv, hash

**By using this code I'm able to hash only 1 record without any errors or warnings. How can I hash a hundred thousand records taken as input from the CSV file?**

```
import pandas as pd
proper = []
with open("C:\\Users\\krupa\\Downloads\\proper.csv","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        tokens = line.split(',')
        order_id =tokens[0]
        country = tokens[1]

        proper.append([order_id,country])

        #print(proper)
proper = {}
with open("C:\\Users\\krupa\\Downloads\\proper.csv","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        tokens = line.split(',')
        order_id =tokens[0]
        country = tokens[1]
        proper[order_id] = country
#print(proper)
def get_hash(key):
    key = int(key, base=10)
    hash_key = 0
    for i in range(key):
        hash_key += 1
    return hash_key % 100
get_hash('503618705')

class HashTable:  
    def __init__(self):
        self.MAX = 100
        self.arr = [None for i in range(self.MAX)]

    def get_hash(self, key):
        key = int(key, base=10)
        hash_key = 0
        for i in range(key):
            hash_key += 1
        return hash_key % self.MAX

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        h = self.get_hash(index)
        return self.arr[h]

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        h = self.get_hash(key)
        self.arr[h] = val    

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        h = self.get_hash(key)
        self.arr[h] = None
t = HashTable()
t["503618705"] = "Tanzania"
t.arr
print(t.arr)
```

**The code is free of errors but I want to hash all the records in the CSV File**

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do, is acctually use your methods.
right now you `__init__` a new object `t`. Then you are refering to a index in your `list` and set `"Tanzania"` as value. så you actually dont use your methods in your object `t` only the function `list`, so what you can do is (I hope I understanded your question correctly.):

```
lst = ['Sweden', 'Germany', 'Pakistan', 'Syria', 'Norway']
idx = ["1234", "30", "500", "2034", "443"]

def get_hash(key):
    key = int(key, base=10)
    hash_key = 0
    for i in range(key):
        hash_key += 1
    return hash_key % 100
get_hash('50')

class HashTable:  
    def __init__(self):
        self.MAX = 100
        self.arr = [None for i in range(self.MAX)]

    def get_hash(self, key):
        key = int(key, base=10)
        hash_key = 0
        for i in range(key):
            hash_key += 1
        return hash_key % self.MAX

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        h = self.get_hash(index)
        return self.arr[h]

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        h = self.get_hash(key)
        self.arr[h] = val    

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        h = self.get_hash(key)
        self.arr[h] = None
t = HashTable()
for n, i in enumerate(lst):
    t.__setitem__(idx[n], lst[n])
for i in range(len(idx)):
    print(t.__getitem__(idx[i]))
    print(t.get_hash(idx[i]))
```

Comment: I guess my question was not clear, sorry for that. I have to take the input from the CSV file. i want the entire order_id column to be read through the code and hash each order_id

Comment: Change idx with order_id[i] in the get_hash function.